# Download Excel_data.xls compare with excel_local.xlsx and import

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will download some Excel data from a webpage, then compare the data to my local file and import the data if there is a duplicate I would like it to add a number to the duplicate in the local Excel file.  Example...

excel1.xls downloaded
excel2local.xlsx

The sheets have the below data:

#### excel1.xls

```
Name_1 | birth City_1 | email_1
Jim    | Seattle      | jim@blah.com
Mike   | New York     | mike@ha.com
```

#### excel2local.xlsx

```
entries | First  | email         | City
1       | Steve  | steve@you.com | Redmond
1       | frank  | frank@ha.com  | Bozeman
1       | Mike   | mike@ha.com   | New York
```

After the download, compare, and import I would like it to look like this...

#### excel2local.xlsx

```
entries | First  | email         | City
1       | Steve  | steve@you.com | Redmond
1       | frank  | frank@ha.com  | Bozeman
2       | Mike   | mike@ha.com   | New York 
1       | Jim    | jim@blah.com  | Seattle
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you stuck with an XLSX? Working with CSV files would be infinitely easier.

Comment: I would use the Power Query add-in for this. The rough outline would be: Query1 - load table from excel1, rename columns to match excel2. Query2 - load table from excel2, append Query1, group by First with Sum of Entries.

Comment: @TimFerrill I can use CSV if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell You have two options:

1. Using Excel automation (Excel object model):    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211632/read-excel-sheet-in-powershell
2. Using data access libraries:
   http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/09/11/how-can-i-read-from-excel-without-using-excel.aspx